# Why can't mock static method in Spring condition

Tags: java, mockito

this is my code.

```
class ACondition extends SpringBootConditoin {
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (Config.isA()) {
            return new ConditionOutcome(true, "ok");
        } else {
            return new ConditionOutcome(false, "error");
        }
    }
}

class BCondition extends SpringBootConditoin {
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        if (Config.isA()) {
            return new ConditionOutcome(false, "error");
        } else {
            return new ConditionOutcome(true, "ok");
        }
    }
}

@Service
@Conditional(ACondition.class)
class APolicy implements Policy {
    ...
}

@Service
@Conditional(BCondition.class)
class BPolicy implements Policy {
    ...
}

class PolicyManager {
    @Autowired
    @Getter
    List<Policy> policyList;
    ...
}
```

the default value of Config.isA() is true.
I want to make Config.isA() to return false. so I use Mockito.mockstatic.

```
@Autowired
PolicyManager manager;

@Test
public void get_B_policy() {
    try(MockedStatic<Config> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Config.class) {
        mocked.when(() -> Config.isA()).thenReturn(false);
        List<Policy> policyList = manager.getPolicyList();
        assertEquals(1, policyList.size()); // this is right
        assertTrue(policyList.get(0) instanceof BPolicy); // this is not right
    }
}
```

Why can't mock the online method?

by the way. If I test the BCondition class, the Config.isA() can be mocked. I can enter the branch which I want. It does not work only in conditional annotation.

Comment: If you replace `()->Config.isA()` with `Config::isA`(the method reference), does it still not work?

Comment: It also returns true. I think **() -> Config.isA()** and **Confg::isA** is the same code.

Comment: What version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: the Mockito version is 3.9.0. java version is 8. bytebuddy version is 1.10.20

Comment: How do you know `isA()` returns true? Have you actually checked by calling `isA()` inside your try block? Or are you assuming `isA()` returns true because your assertions are showing that `policyList.get(0)` is a BPolicy?

Comment: I debug the test. set breakpoint to isA(). it returns true.

Comment: No wonder it's returning true. You're setting a breakpoint at the real `isA()` method, but not the statically mocked method! MockStatic can't magically change the code of a real method to make it return something else. Instead, it changes the method that is called. So what you are seeing by setting the breakpoint is that your code is still calling the _real_ method and not the mocked one. That's because the mocked method is only in effect for the duration of your `try` block. The real method is called during Spring initialization, before your test method. Take another look at SKumar's answer.

Comment: Can you share your `Config` class? Also why do you insist on having this method be static?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Context is already loaded by the time it is reaching the Test Case. Hence, Manager already has selected `APolicy`.

If you could move the static mock config before spring context loads, then it should match your expectations.

`mocked.when(() -> Config.isA()).thenReturn(false);`

One way of doing it is initialising the static Mock like below -

**Junit4**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PolicyManager.class, APolicy.class, BPolicy.class})
public class ConditionTest
{
    @Autowired
    PolicyManager manager;

    static MockedStatic<Config> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Config.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()
    {
        mocked.when(() -> Config.isA()).thenReturn(false);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void clear()
    {
        mocked.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void get_B_policy() {
        List<Policy> policyList = manager.getPolicyList();
        assertEquals(1, policyList.size()); // this is right
        assertTrue(policyList.get(0) instanceof BPolicy); // should work now
    }
}
```

**Junit5**
Please use Jupiter's annotations.

```
@Autowired
PolicyManager manager;

static MockedStatic<Config> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Config.class);

@BeforeAll
public static void setup() { 
    mocked.when(() -> Config.isA()).thenReturn(true);
}

@AfterAll
public static void clear() {
    mocked.close();
}

@Test
public void get_B_policy() {
    List<Policy> policyList = manager.getPolicyList();
    assertEquals(1, policyList.size()); // this is right
    assertTrue(policyList.get(0) instanceof BPolicy); // should work now
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The isA() still return true. and the MockedStatic should be closed after test.

Comment: @S.Lee Strange, the solution is working for me. Anyways, updated test code.

Comment: @S.Lee Incase you are using Junit5, please refer updated answer.

Comment: it works like a charm for me! Thank you for the solution